# Reducing the signal frequency

Tags: analog, frequency, pulse

I have a sawtooth signal: roughly speaking, the duration of the "tooth" is 1 ms. Is it possible in the analog world to thin out this signal? For example, leave only every third, tenth "tooth", etc. I would like to have only onе tooth every 0.1s.

Sorry for the dumb question. This was one of the ways to get a sawtooth signal of the desired frequency. Now I have an adequate solution to this problem. But a terrible curiosity haunts me.
[image]

Comment: The blue waveform doesn't look very "analog world"-ish so, what do you mean by "analog world"?

Comment: @andy-aka, sorry for the confusing picture. I received this sawtooth signal from a square wave using an integrator. Blue waveform is the original square wave.

Answer (score 0):

"analog world" is pretty much the world where you cannot count discrete event "times". So, by its very definition, your problem is pretty much digital! Luckily, that makes it easier (remember: having two values that you need to roughly recreate through your circuit is easier than having an infinite amount that you need to more or less exactly deal with. In the end, that's why analog computing is a niche thing, and both the supercomputers and the most power-saving microcontrollers are digital, not analog computers.)

So, you have the original square wave signal. Work with that; it's easier to detect rising edges rather than slopes! You can then do exactly the same you did to your original square wave to the divided-down "square wave".

Anyway, classical use case for a counter. There's very many *counter IC*s (and if you search for `counter IC` on this website, you'll find plenty circuits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was already able to get a signal of the desired shape and frequency.
"Reducing the frequency" is my infantile desire to bring digital approaches to the analog world.
Is it possible to do this somehow, for example, with a transistor: apply a step voltage, and the transistor will pass the desired part of the signal?

Comment: yeah, you take a transistor, operate it so that it swings between saturation and 0 current, then concatenate more transistors to build a counter. What you want is to count. It's a digital problem, no matter how good or bad you approximate i.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus gives a fine answer - if you want a whole sawtooth to disappear, or two consecutive sawteeth to disappear, or a string of three....etc, then that's a counting problem. And Marcus' solution: count rectangular pulses going in - that's the sane approach that any modern designer would consider first.

But the OP wants an analog solution: many years ago, when digital counting techniques were not considered by designers, a semi-analog approach *would* be used (and *was* used)...

The technique couples two oscillators together so that the output of one influences the frequency of the other. If you wish to study theory, search for [injection-locked-oscillators](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/RSep04.pdf). Marcus' counting solution is superior, since coupled oscillators would result in sawtooth slope varying between sawtooth stepping, even though they may lock when their frequencies are close to integer-multiples of each other.

An example of coupling is a **[blocking oscillator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pulse_circuits/pulse_circuits_blocking_oscillators.htm)**. Such a circuit was used to synchronize a TV's horizontal oscillator to video timing pulses.